# Storing data with validity time window

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with PHP/MySql. Frequently, I encounter the problem that I need a "valid from" and a " valid to" column, and only read the matching rows that are valid today.

This makes the SQL statements more difficult to read (adding the extra conditions) and one needs to know (not forget) to add the additional conditions.

Is there a common approach for this problem?

Comment: Not that I know of. Your approach is pretty much all there is, to my knowledge.

Comment: show us the extra condition

Comment: I don't know whether it's a common approach, or even recommended as it makes the application harder to port, but you *could* create a [UDF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-function-loadable.html) called something like `IS_CURRENT` which checks the `valid_from` and `valid_to` columns and returns a boolean... it would tidy up the queries a little.

Comment: you also can create a View with this where. than it only returns valid rows and you can add the other where